# Where do I define the domain to be used by url_for() in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

When I call `url_for('index')` it will generate `'/'` but there are times where I'd like it to generate `'domain.tld/'` instead. I can't find in the documentation where I would specify this. Do I just need to do `'domain.tld/%s' % url_for('index')`?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

[`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for) takes an `_external` keyword argument that will return an absolute (rather than relative) URL.  I believe you will need to set a `SERVER_NAME` config key with your root domain to make it work correctly.

Comment: That worked. Just by setting app.config['SERVER_NAME']. I didn't need _external. Thanks.

Comment: Conversely, I only had to add `_external=True` as an argument in my `url_for()` call and didn't have to set the `SERVER_NAME` config.

Comment: I am setting this `SERVER_NAME = 'http://localhost:5000'`, but it ignores the port number `5000`. Why is so?

Comment: Set it just to "localhost:5000". You control scheme ("http" or "https") with separate setting: PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME

Comment: I have a problem with _external that  I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816265/url-for-with-external-true-on-heroku-doesnt-append-the-server-name-on-the-url

Comment: When `url_for()` is used with `_external=True` in the context of an incoming HTTP request then scheme, host, port are all taken from the _incoming request_, even if SERVER_NAME is configured. I quickly wrote about my analysis here: https://github.com/conbench/conbench/pull/454#issuecomment-1326338524. (the HOST header field of the incoming HTTP request is certainly consulted, and valid requests _do_ contain that, as of RFC 7230)