# url_for() didn't work will when I use nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, fastcgi

The code in my template is this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('.post',id=post.id) }}"><h2 >{{ post.title }}</h2></a>
```

My blog url is **localhost:5000/index/all**,It looks like(use app.run()):

[image]

The url for first post is **localhost:5000/post/10**

But if I use fcgi and nginx, it look like this:

[image]

The url for first post is **localhost:5000/index/all/post/10** which not exist actually.

Why url_for() didn't return right url when I use nginx?

Comment: it's very hard to see the problem here, please consider re-phrasing for clarity. In general, nginx has nothing to do with url_for, which is internal to flask. You should check that the page renders properly with what you expect by inspecting the link element on the page itself using the browser's "inspect element" functionality. To me the '.post' seems a bit strange, not sure why there whould be a '.' (dot) there.

Comment: now this is clearer, you have a relative vs absolute issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162634/where-do-i-define-the-domain-to-be-used-by-url-for-in-flask, i think _external=True in the url_for params should work in your case.

Comment: @GG_Python I think I'm not describe my problem clear.It's looks similar but different question with that question.Never mind.I solve this problem and I will add answer in the follow

Answer (score 0):

I also ask this question in [Github](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/issues/53).Thanks for miguelgrinberg's help,it's solved

FastCGI tends to have issues like this, where for odd reasons the CGI environment variables passed to the application are set incorrectly.

I add two line in manage.py and it works well in nginx.

```
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import CGIRootFix


app = CGIRootFix(app,app_root='/')
```