# Flask url_for ignoring port

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app running on port 5000. My server admin has configured nginx to forward this to port 5001 (sorry if I have the wrong terminology: the Flask app is running on port 5000, but the app is publicly accessible at `http://the_url:5001`).

All routes accessed directly in the browser work, but any redirect using `url_for()` seem to result in the port being missed from the URL — i.e. `redirect(url_for('index'))` redirects to `http://the_url/` rather than `http://the_url:5001/` (where the `@app.route("/")` triggers the function `index()`).

How do I make sure Flask adds the correct port when redirecting? If I change the default port to 5001, the nginx configuration will not work as it expects the app to be runnning on port 5000?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I define the domain to be used by url\_for() in Flask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162634/where-do-i-define-the-domain-to-be-used-by-url-for-in-flask)

Comment: Read commentaries for answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162634/where-do-i-define-the-domain-to-be-used-by-url-for-in-flask. You should remove 'http' part from config.

Comment: I'd seen previous answers, but setting the `app.config["SERVER_NAME"]` variable stops the site running ... unless I am doing this wrong? (I just set it to: `the_url:5001`)

Comment: @user2672537, you need to setup `SERVER_NAME` = `localhost:5001`

Comment: What helped me was this url (it's old, but still worked): https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups

Answer (score 19):

add this to your Nginx config:

`proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`

or

`proxy_set_header Host $host:5001`

[read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414810/whats-the-difference-of-host-and-http-host-in-nginx)

Comment: Also use url_for(x, _external=True) so that it construct the URL based on headers

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to the nginx config.

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        }
```

This way you can have your flask app running on localhost:5000. If you set up your `server { listen 80; }` config correctly (at the top of the config) the user should be able to hit port 80 and it will redirect to internal 5000 port. All my `url_for()` work perfectly.