# url_for with _external=True on heroku doesn't append the server name on the URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, flask

I have deploy an application on Heroku but the problem is when my application send email it doesn't append the name of my server in the URL:

```
content = Content("text/html", verification_email.format(user["first_name"],
                                                             url_for("register.display_register_form",
                                                                     token=token.decode("utf-8"), external=True)))
```

But the link I'm receiving in my email is:

```
http:///register_account/DnsJpXw_QIcPYeDHEg_fipB2kRiJBUj2RI6I9cI4Yl4w6K9ohbZRMVqBInuV0aOsBT4Zqt69X8MfhNfnys4s-DAQmgu1OPBwmSQnzAELvdcCyiZtkJGSY8_dQ799FOewtBDkvqR1D8XHmvVxgaVqbwSjdEBnvFsBBHMQCic%3D/verify?external=True
```

I have problems with this URL:

- It is not https and it should be since it's host on heroku
- The server name doesn't appear in the URL only `///` like if the server name was blank

What should I do to have the correct URL `https://my-server-name/register_account...`?

**EDIT**

I tried to set in my config.py file with the following variable to:

SERVER_NAME = "http://my-server-58140.herokuapp.com"

It generated errors in my path and I couldn't access any URL for example, the following one could be access before but when defining my `SERVER_NAME` it didn't anymore:

```
http://my-server-58140.herokuapp.com/home
```

**EDIT**

My flask application is configured:

```
SERVER_NAME = os.environ.get('SERVER_NAME')
DEBUG = True
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Where the environnement variable is set to `0.0.0.0:5000` on my localhost and: `my-server-58140.herokuapp.com` on my production server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To generate the correct URL, these two Flask configuration values need to be set:

- `SERVER_NAME` to the name of your website,
- and `PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME` to `https`.

See the [documentation for `url_for()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for) and [how to configure a Flask application](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/).

EDIT: Additionally, the parameter in `url_for` should be `_external` and not `external`.

Comment: I uptdated my answer, is the SERVER_NAME and PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME must be defined as Heroku environment variable?

Comment: Could you try removing `http://` from `SERVER_NAME`? No, there's no need to define these as Heroku environment variables.

Comment: Ok I add a SERVER_NAME but it doesn't work my email still receive a link like: http:///register_account/... without the main domain name

Comment: I have the same problem using localhost, I set my SERVER_NAME = "0.0.0.0:5000" but the email the application is sending me are build like this: http:///register_account/...

Comment: Could you please edit your original post to show how your Flask application is configured? Also, what's `verification_email`?

Comment: Try changing `external=True` to `_external=True`.

Comment: Thanks that was a problem with "_external" **facepalm** can you add this o your answer then I will validate it