# How to use url_for without request context?

Tags: flask, celery

Flask application and Celery worker share the same code (not necessarily same host). Celery task has an application context. However, some of the code called in the celery task uses `url_for` to generate URLs. Of course, celery task works outside request context and does not have the "base URL" for URL generation.

Base URL can be provided to the task, but what is the elegant way to enable `url_for`? It's not practical for the task to receive all required URLs as task parameters. The URLs are generated in templates (eg, HTML for email messages) as well as in some functions. By elegant is meant a way, which may potentially allow the same worker to support different base URLs, so solution with base URL in some static config (or environment variable) is not enough. That is, I am aware of [Where do I define the domain to be used by url_for() in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162634/where-do-i-define-the-domain-to-be-used-by-url-for-in-flask) , but it does not solve the problem stated here.

```
# in task module
from celery import Celery, Task

class ExampleTask(Task):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with self.flask_app.app_context():
            return super(ExampleTask, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    ...

celery_app = Celery('example_package',  task_cls="example_package.ExampleTask", ...)

def init_celery_app(flask_app):
    celery_app.conf.update(flask_app.config)
    #...
    celery_app.Task.flask_app = flask_app
    return celery_app

# in some other module
from examplepackage import celery_app as celery

@celery.task(name="example_task", ...)
def example_task(parameters):
    do_something_on(parameters)
    # That do_something uses url_for

# worker_module
flask_and_celery_config_file_path = os.environ["FLASK_CONFIG"]
flask_app = create_app(flask_and_celery_config_file_path)
celery_app = init_celery_app(flask_app)

# Running:
celery worker -A worker_module.celery_app ...

# Somewhere in Flask app code:
example_task.delay(parameters)
```

As suggested in the answer below, tried:

```
class ExampleTask(Task):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.flask_app.config.update({
            'SERVER_NAME': 'my_host', 
            'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'https'})
        with self.flask_app.app_context():
            return super(ExampleTask, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

It worked, but it remains unclear whether those config variables can be really dynamic without affecting other threads?

To clarify: How to change domain per task preferably without initializing the whole flask_app?

Comment: How do you run `celery tasks`? from a "end point"?

Comment: It's simple: `task_function.delay(parameters)`

Comment: why you can't just put `url_for` as `parameter`  from `endpoint`?

Comment: `url_for` is a function. I bet it will not survive a journey via rabbitmq

Comment: I mean `function result` send as `parameter`.

Comment: This will mean I need to know before hand which URLs are needed. And this is what I am trying to avoid because there is no reliable way to find it out plus it will mean the code will be fragile and change in one part will require change in another.

Comment: Why do you think *"It's not practical for the task to receive all required URLs as task parameters"*?

Comment: It's impractical because then it will create a point of rigidity: Codebase for handling requests and background tasks is shared. It will not be as easy to background a task if one need to trace down all the url_fors, in all possible situations. Even more: Adding new URL to any template will require changing completely unrelated code (task signature). Failing to do that will result in a bug. That is, having to explicitly provide all URLs (beyond base URL) breaks single responsibility principle and is not DRY. Getting URLs is ubiquitous in code, so it's not practical to pin them down.

Answer (score 0):

This has been practically resolved by providing the task one example of URI and using a function like:

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

def get_url_for(url_instance, app_prefix):
    """Approximating application url_for. Suitable for static and one app routes. Assumes a prefix to resolve "relative"
    URLs.
    """
    split_uri = urlsplit(url_instance)
    url_adapter = celery.Task.flask_app.url_map.bind(
        split_uri.netloc,
        script_name='/',
        url_scheme=split_uri.scheme
    )

    def url_for(endpoint, **values):
        appctx = _ctx_stack.top
        external = values.pop('_external', True)
        anchor = values.pop('_anchor', None)
        method = values.pop('_method', "GET")
        scheme = values.pop('_scheme', split_uri.scheme)
        appctx.app.inject_url_defaults(endpoint, values)
        absolute_endpoint = app_prefix + endpoint if endpoint.startswith(".") else endpoint
        rv = url_adapter.build(absolute_endpoint, values, method=method, force_external=True)
        if anchor is not None:
            rv += '#' + url_quote(anchor)
        return rv

    return url_for
```

This also requires subclassing celery `Task` and redefining it's call method:

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    with self.flask_app.app_context():
        return super(MyTask, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

so that task is run in the app context.

This answer is only giving direction. More details may need to be filled in depending on the Flask application. For example, that instead of Flask magic Flask framework related services are propagated to subfunctions explicitly. (It's in any case good architectural approach not to rely on Flask magical services like request, url_for, current_user deeper in the code base. Here "deeper" means anywhere but in the views).