# Flask _external=True not working as expected

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I have the following `flask` application that I'm serving using `nginx`, `supervisor` and `gunicorn`. I am running the app as follows using a factory setup method in `wsgi.py`:

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

def main():
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have the following email that I'm trying to render:

```
<p>Please <a href="{{ url_for('users.confirm_new_user', token=token, _external=True) }}"><b>click here</b></a> to confirm your email address.</p>
```

However, when I click the above link the email just links to `localhost:8000/users/new/confirm/confirmation-token`.

**How do I get the link to take me to `https://example.com/users/new/confirm/confirmation-token` instead of `localhost`, please?**

I tried adding the following to the `config.py` file, which is loaded within the `create_app` method, but it just broke the application:

```
PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME = 'https'
SERVER_NAME = 'example.com'
```

My `nginx` configuration looks like this (I'm not sure if this is the problem):

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  access_log /var/log/example/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/example/nginx.error.log;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
  location /static {
    alias /home/alexjrlewis/example/example/app/static;
    expires 30d;
  }
}
```

Comment: `config.py` doesn't mean anything. Are you actually using that configuration somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do I define the domain to be used by url\_for() in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162634/where-do-i-define-the-domain-to-be-used-by-url-for-in-flask)

Comment: @KenKinder Hey, `config.py` is loaded within the `create_app` method. But setting `SERVER_NAME` and `PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME` seem to break the application for some reason ... ?